# AppEngine testing User Service from the command-line

Tags: python, google-app-engine, protorpc

How can I test the `user service` from the command-line using `curl`?

Let's say I have a `protoRPC` service running and I issue something like:

`curl -H 'content-type:application/json'    -d '{"name":"test1"}'   http://localhost:8080/api.context_create`

but this service requires a logged-in user.  How can I simulate one?

Comment: FYI it's possible to test from browser, using an extension such as https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to do it in two steps (see [this](http://johannilsson.com/2011/04/13/authenticated-requests-on-app-engine.html) link for the details). The first is submitting a request to:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8000/_ah/login -d "email=youremail@here.com&action=Log+In" -c -
```

The response will look something like this:

```
localhost FALSE / FALSE 0 dev_appserver_login "youremail@here.com:False:0123456789101112"
```

You can then submit a request to your target page, using the cookie provided. In your case (assuming the above cookie) you could try:

```
curl -H 'content-type:application/json' \
    -d '{"name":"test1"}' \
    -b "dev_appserver_login="youremail@here.com:False:0123456789101112"" \
    http://localhost:8080/api.context_create
```